# Projection of periodic trajectories

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, periodic-functions

Let $(\bar x(t),\bar u(t)),\, t\in [0,1]$ solution of
$$
\left \{
\begin{array}{l}
\dot x_1 (t) = u(t)\, f(x(t)) \\
\dot x_2 (t) = u(t)\\
x_1(0) = 0, x_1(1)=1 \\
x_2(0) = x_2(1)
\end{array}
\right.
$$
where $x=(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is 
the state, $f$ is a given vector field  and $u$ is the control function.

For $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, we define $v(t) = \bar u(t+\alpha)$ (well defined because $\bar u$ is periodic).

Do we have that $(\bar x(t), v(t)),\, t\in[0,1] $ solution of the previous control system?

Comment: is there any reason to think this conjecture is true?

Comment: No no reason but how to proof?

Comment: the statement does not strike me as an obvious fact, so I'd probably try to find a counterexample first. It looks like a rigorous proof would be difficult here, even if the statement is true. Is there a specific $f(x)$ you can suggest which meets the IC's? Then you can at least try to do some calculations and get a feeling whether or not the statement is true.